# "You must feed a value for placeholder tensor" error while creating model which composed of two submodels, all created using functional API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

While implementing variational autoencoder I came across this issue. Following minimally reproducible example has a simple `encoder`, `decoder` and `vae` all created using functional API. `vae` consists of `encoder` and `decoder` as usual. I'm using custom callback to get intermediate layer predictions.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((1,))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32)(inputs)
encoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((32,))
outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)(inputs)
decoder = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input((1,))
x = encoder(inputs)
outputs = decoder(x)
vae = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        get_output = tf.keras.backend.function(
            inputs = self.model.layers[0].input,
            outputs = self.model.layers[1].output
        )
        print("\nPrediction:",get_output(X))

X = np.random.random_sample((8,1))
y = X
vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
vae.fit(X, y, epochs=2, callbacks=[CustomCallback()])
```

I get following error when I run above code:

```
<ipython-input-3-fd96ce817cad> in on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs)
      5             outputs = self.model.layers[1].output
      6         )
----> 7         print("\nPrediction:",get_output(X))
.
.
InvalidArgumentError:  You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input_1' with dtype float and shape [?,1]
     [[node input_1 (defined at <ipython-input-3-fd96ce817cad>:5) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_539]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

but when train only the encoder like this:

```
X = np.random.random_sample((8,1))
y = np.random.random_sample((8,32))
encoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
encoder.fit(X, y, epochs=2, callbacks=[CustomCallback()])
```

it works fine.

What's causing this error? How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the correct way to define it

```
inp_enc = tf.keras.layers.Input((1,))
out_enc = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=32)(inp_enc)
encoder = tf.keras.Model(inp_enc, out_enc)
    
out_dec = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=1)(encoder.output)
decoder = tf.keras.Model(encoder.input, out_dec)

vae = tf.keras.Model(encoder.input, decoder.output)

class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        get_output = tf.keras.backend.function(
            inputs = self.model.layers[0].input,
            outputs = self.model.layers[1].output
        )
        print("\nPrediction:", get_output(X))

X = np.random.random_sample((8,1))
y = X
vae.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
vae.fit(X, y, epochs=2, callbacks=[CustomCallback()])
```

Comment: Although it works perfectly fine, the `decoder` has lost its semantics, it's no more a `decoder`. In fact, there isn't any difference between `vae` and `decoder`.

Comment: Exactly, it's feed with the original input data